# As a language how stable is Groovy?

Tags: groovy

As a language how stable is Groovy? Do any big names use it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524158/how-popular-is-groovy-grails-in-the-corporate-world

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791837/how-stable-is-the-groovy-language

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Groovy for about 2 years and yes, it is stable. So far, I haven't faced any bugs in the language itself. The creators of the language release often. There is great tool support and there are many mature libraries and frameworks based on it. Take for example [Grails](http://grails.org/), a Rails-like framework. If you go to its page, you will see that a lot of BIG names, such as LinkedIn, Netflix and Atlassian are using it. I myself am using Groovy in many projects with Ericsson, which is a BIG name too.

Answer (score -3):

As for "**big names**", there may be some (you shouldn't care). Obviously, nevertheless, Groovy's got a basic problem with its [poor performance](http://www.google.com/search?q=groovy+performance) compared to Java. Positively, it's doubtable that Groovy is used in any mission-critical projects where scalability counts.

Regarding **stability** (as in the "absence of bugs"), take a look at the Groovy [issue tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project+%3D+GROOVY+AND+resolution+%3D+Unresolved+AND+priority+%3D+Major+ORDER+BY+key+DESC&mode=hide). Enjoy ROFL'ing at several bugs where Groovy (again and again) has stumbled upon its own "magic". - Groovy bugs are numerous, and often unresolved for years.

Regarding **stability** again (as in "backwards compatibility"), I'm too new to Groovy to say much about that. Nevertheless, the closures syntax had changed without a compatibility layer provided. (This would never ever happen in the Java language.)

- When looking at those points from a Java perspective, Groovy is a kindergarten. From a Scala perspective even, Groovy will never grow up.

- Which is not to say that Groovy had no clear advantages in other scopes (like, there is Grails). But you've asked about these.

Comment: I've been doing Groovy development since 2007 and do not recognize myself in your description of the language. The one thing I can agree with is that Groovy's performance is worse than that of Java. But, that's not a big issue for most applications because most applications do not do that kind of number crunching.

Comment: As for performance, Groovy's concept of "runtime metaprogramming" (everything related to the MetaClass interface) prevents it from ever coming close to completely compiled languages. At this central point, Groovy is broken by design. Even James Strachan, original creator of Groovy, "honestly" admits that. - As for the "database bottleneck", database and Groovy operations are executed sequentially, so the bottleneck just gets taller with Groovy. - As for applications just "waiting for the user", let's talk about other types of applications.

Comment: Oops, my comment has been meant a reply to a comment that has been edited, completely, in the meantime. Sorry.

Comment: Groovy is not slow, take a look here: http://nathan.crause.name/entries/programming/speed-ruby-vs-groovy , it's almost the same speed than raw Java.