# How to get classpath in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How can I get current value of `CLASSPATH` in Groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
System.getProperty('java.class.path')
```

Comment: It's empty :( Is it possible to get classpath form class loader?

Comment: Groovy seems to do funky stuff, and the java.class.path does not contain the classpath passed with groovy's -cp command line option.

Comment: It shows only groovy jar - why http://stackoverflow.com/a/27131375/1042297 is not accepted answer ?

Answer (score 17):

Shameless stolen from http://blog.blindgaenger.net/print_groovys_classpath_for_debugging.html
This code will go up the classloader tree and printout each classloader and the associated classpath.

```
def printClassPath(classLoader) {
  println "$classLoader"
  classLoader.getURLs().each {url->
     println "- ${url.toString()}"
  }
  if (classLoader.parent) {
     printClassPath(classLoader.parent)
  }
}
printClassPath this.class.classLoader
```

Comment: I found the strangest thing about this method running inside Maven run with the gmaven-plus plugin. I noticed that it made a difference if Maven was run with or without the 'clean' goal. If the 'clean' goal is not specified then this method appends `C:/Users/user/dev/project/target/classes/` (note the trailing slash). Then when passing this classpath to `xjc` it won't find extensions. It is only if I manually strip the trailing slash does it find the extensions on the class path. Something like `if (path.endsWith("/")) { return path.substring(0, path.length() - 2) }`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the classpath from the SystemClassLoader, providing it is an URLClassLoader:

```
URL[] classPathUrls = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getURLs();
```

Comment: Same thing: both the `CLASSPATH` environment variable and the `-classpath` in the command line have no effect on this list. At least in my case it is identical to what I see in the property `java.class.path`.

Comment: However, see http://groovy.codehaus.org/How+can+I+dynamically+add+a+library+to+the+classpath about dynamically adding a path to classpath. this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL( new URL("file:///d:/drivers/ojdbc14.jar") )

Answer (score 1):

`java.class.path` doesn't work properly, at least in Groovy 2.1.6 (Mac OS X 10.6.8).

`HelloWorld.groovy`:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(def args) {
        System.out.println( "Hello, world!\n");
        System.out.println(System.getenv("CLASSPATH")+"\n");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    }
}
```

Then

```
export CLASSPATH=/etc
groovy -classpath /usr HelloWorld.groovy
```

Result:

```
Hello, World!

/etc

/Applications/groovy-2.1.6/lib/groovy-2.1.6.jar
```

Now, this is `HelloWorld.java`: (I had to change it a bit as Groovy and Java are not 100% compatible):

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         System.out.println( "Hello, world!\n");
         System.out.println(System.getenv("CLASSPATH")+"\n");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    }
}
```

Now:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
export CLASSPATH=/etc
java -classpath /usr HelloWorld
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
etc. ...................
```

Then:

```
java -classpath /usr:. HelloWorld
```

Result:

```
Hello, world!

/etc

/usr:.
```

I'll update if I find out how to make it work in Groovy...

Answer (score 0):

Get the CLASSPATH and files if you want in the those CLASSPATH if needed you can view it

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path", ".").tokenize(File.pathSeparator).each {
                               println it                             
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def classpath = System.properties["java.class.path"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's empty when I'm using Groovy inside [gmaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code). Is it possible to get classpath from class loader somehow?