# jenkins shows "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: mysql, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I wrote a jenkins pipeline with groovy that connects with the mysql database.  But when it connects to mysql it shows"

> **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

". Is there is any way to resolve this error. If not how can I connect do mysql operations with jenkins pipeline. I wrote a below code to connect with mysql database.

```
def props = [user: '', password: '', allowMultiQueries: 'true'] as Properties
def url = 'jdbc:mysql://myserver:port/'
def driver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, props, driver)
echo 'Database connection sucess'
```

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a JDBC driver to a Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014632/how-to-add-a-jdbc-driver-to-a-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: I am not clear with that answer can you please elaborate how to add jdbc driver in jenkins to avoid this exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: It is possible to use @Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true) in groovy jenkins pipeline script. Jenkins shows "General error during conversion: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab"

Comment: Did you install the plugin?

Comment: I installed two jenkins plugin "MySQL Database Plugin" and "MySQL Job Databases". I am using ubuntu operating system. what else I have to install?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting that error is accuse MySQL JDBC connection jar is not accessible. 
Now possible reasons could be

- That you have not updated your DataBase plugin as to use JDBC connector classes available in the Jenkins pipeline groovy scripts you need to update the DataBase plugin.
- Also, use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/MySQL+Database+Plugin to configure your connection

Comment: I am not clear with this answer can you please elaborate how to add jdbc driver in jenkins to avoid this exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"