# connecting to mysql db from jenkins pipeline not wroking

Tags: mysql, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins v2.219 installed (running in docker if it matters) and iv'e installed:

Database plugin v1.5

MySQL Database Plugin v1.3

I've created the simplest pipeline to check the db connection and it doesn't work.
My pipeline is:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
node { 
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://<mysql_db_host>:3306/<db_name>", "myuser","mypass", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    sql.execute "SELECT * FROM table"   
}
```

And when I run it I get:

```
Rebuilds build #47
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline_playground
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:543)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader.loadClass(CallSiteClassLoader.java:54)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.loadClass(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:60)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java_lang_Class$forName$1.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:191)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onStaticCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:189)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:193)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:98)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:405)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:281)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've also tried running it without: "Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")" that gave me  "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ..."

UPDATE:

btw, i do see:

database-mysql.jar, mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar, protobuf-java-3.6.1.jar

at: /plugins/database-mysql/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Please check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014632/how-to-add-a-jdbc-driver-to-a-jenkins-pipeline) I think this question is already answered over there.

Comment: saw it. it's not solved there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and this was how I fixed it.
First link the database jar files to your jenkins system.
To find out where jenkins is looking for jar files go to the script console of your jenkins server and run this code

```
println System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs")
```

**Result**

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.fc29.x86_64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext

Next go to one of those directories and create symlinks to the jar files of the plugins. On a linux system...

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.fc29.x86_64/jre/lib/ext

ln -s /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/database-mysql/WEB-INF/lib/database-mysql.jar 
ln -s /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/database-mysql/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar
```

Restart jenkins so that the jar files are loaded.

Now you can query your MySQL database from your jenkins pipeline

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
node{
    def conn = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cms", "fred", "fredpassword", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    def rows = conn.rows("select username from users LIMIT 10")
    assert rows.size() == 10
    println rows.join('\n')
}
```

Comment: Hi @aberpaul, can you please suggest what needs to be done for java 11, where 
println System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs") is not there and 
java.class.path = /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
In this case, how to add the jar files?